# Controlling two-pole contactor using Arduino

Tags: power, relay, mosfet

I am working with [Packard C230C contactor](https://openev.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/attachments/6066213440) to develop own EVSE. For a simple start i just want to toggle contactor using Arduino. OpenEVSE is already doing it. Just want to know how do they do it and some circuit explanation.

Reference : OpenEVSE Setup
 [image]

Comment: the gray wires control the relay .... research how to control a relay with an Arduino .... also research how relays work  ..... btw: the link that you posted is bogus

Comment: I get grey wire controls contactor. But the voltage at that wire is around 120v while toggling a contactor state. generally relay is also +5v so question is how do you control 120~220v relay from arduino

Comment: @SurajJorwekar using a second relay that is controllable by 5V, that one doesn't need to switch a lot of power so can be a cheap one.

Comment: I use this module, controlled by 3.3 V pin of esp8266, powered with 5V to switch 10A AC http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-SPDT_Relay_30A/

Answer (score -1):

Get solid state relays that have a operating voltage of 5V and can switch Mains AC